# Flutter how I will grab argument int value from map object

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in dart and flutter

I have used `pushNamed` to send category id to category_details page

```
onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          CategoryDetailsPage.routeName, 
          arguments: <String, int>{'catId': id},
    );
},
```

In category details page build method I have tried to receive this argument like below way

```
final categoryId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

After print, in console I got the value as a MAP

flutter: `{catId: 1}`

So I tried to access the catId value like

```
int id = categoryId!["catId"];
```

I'm getting below error,

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.
```

How can I grab this id for continue my next integration ?

Comment: Please just cast arguments to Map by using 'as Map'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try casting the object to a map like this:

```dart
final Map<String, int> categoryId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, int>;

int? id = categoryId!["catId"];
```

Comment: Maybe a try/catch block should be applied as well while trying to do this, to prevent any runtime exception